# Jenkins build - docker: not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to run a jenkins job with jenkins on k8s (jenkins-master and jenkins-slave pods). The images used for both jenkins-master and jenkins-pods have docker installed. I am facing the same issue while running jenkins-jobs:

docker build -t prod-build-tag:mpf-ui-16-1443337293670 --build-arg BUNDLE_ENTERPRISE__CONTRIBSYS__COM .
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/*****/script.sh: 1: docker: not found
Kindly suggest on what needs to be done.

In the jenkins-slave pods, when I try to run
docker run -it  bash
docker version
It states that docker service is not started.

How do I run systemctl enable docker.service from a Dockerfile ?

Comment: Does the build agent have docker installed?

Comment: Also, the issue is on jenkins-slave not on jenkins-master.

The error is under:
Running on jenkins-slave-m495f in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/****

Comment: Yes, the build agent has docker installed

Comment: Is it in `PATH`?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'is it in PATH' ?

Comment: The jenkins-master pod is deployed via helm-charts ( a base jenkins/jenkins image added with docker installation steps is used )
The jenkins-slave pod is mentioned in Jenkins UI -Manage nodes and clouds ( a base jenkins/agent image added with docker installation steps is used)

Comment: The fact you're deploying with helm on k8s doesn't mean the actual container that performs the build contains docker.  Check the image you're using as a build agent and see if it contains docker.

Comment: I verified that docker is installed on jenkins-master pod - it is up and running and I logged into the pod to verify.
I can't verify on jenkins-slave as the pod is not running (unless the jenkins job runs successfully, jenkins-slave pod doesn't run). I did a docker image inspect locally on my machine and couldn't gather much information.

Comment: This is the Dockerfile I used for Jenkins-slave image:
FROM jenkins/agent
USER root
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \

Comment: curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io && \
    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.6/docker-

Comment: compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN usermod -u 1001 jenkins && usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't include it all at once

Comment: Please [edit] the question with that information.